# A PHP function to convert decimal ASCII to ASCII char

Tags: php, ascii

I'm at a total loss, attempting to convert an decimal string, not oct, just plain decimal, which varies in character count to plain text.

The string would look like:
495051979899100 (123abcd)

I could use chr() all day if I had a way to predict what the string would contain, but I really don't, so what should I do?

Comment: I'm guessing it'd be a two step process. First convert the decimal string to a hexadecimal one, and then start pulling off 2 characters at a time and converting them to their character equivalent.

Comment: How can you ever know if 4 digits is a 3/1, a 2/2 or a 1/3 combination?

Comment: I think a first problem is disambiguation. How do you subdivide `456` as `45` and `6` or `4` and `56`.

Comment: @MarkBaker: The only solution is assuming that the used ascii is between `32` and `128` so there are no doubles.

Comment: Just for clarity, my initial comment assumed that the decimal value represented one single number, not a concat of decimal values. The concat cannot be reliable converted, as others pointed out.

Comment: @Erik: Well as far as I know, PHP uses `float`s to represent huge numbers. As a result, some part of the number will get lost. So you need to assume you are given the number as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous in the sense that without any assumption, an input string can result in an exponential number of output strings that all satisfy the constraints.

We make the assumption that with ASCII you mean the readable (not control-parts) of ascii. Thus any valid ascii value is between `32` and `128`. As a result, you know that if the first two characters represent a value, strictly less than `32` it will be in the `100+` range.

Your algorithm should do two things concurrently:

- Read out the first two characters.
- If the value is less than `32` then, the the value is in the `100+` range so read three characters and convert, if not it is in the `-100` range, sou convert the two characters.

Or in PHP:

```
$s = "495051979899100";
$n = strlen($s);
$result = "";
for ($x=0; $x<=$n; $x += 2) {
    $temp = intval(substr($s,$x,2));
    if($temp < 32) {
        $temp = intval(substr($s,$x,3));
        if($temp > 128) {
            die "Assumption error";
        }
        $x++;
    }
    $result .= chr($temp);
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: worth to note that if a character that is less than 32 goes into that system, the system will fail miserably.

Comment: @Sharky: I fully agree, but it's the only way one this can be done, since otherwise, the system is ambiguous, thus it can map to an exponential number of strings. I will add the assumption to the answer.

Comment: yea, it's a classic situation where you **must** go to the root of the problem and fix the causes instead of adding more complexity, like on this situation, guessing stuff.

Comment: talking about complexity on my previous comment, now with your edit you say "32 and 128" now, you must update your code also to comply with this statement (your code does not check `>128`) told ya complexity:kill it at the root! dont add more!

Comment: I appreciate all the help! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Yep, wrote almost the same code

```
$str = '495051979899100';
$ind = 0; $out = '';
while($ind < strlen($str))
{
    $two = substr($str, $ind, 2);
    if ($two >= 32) {
        $out .= chr($two);
        $ind += 2;
    } else {
        $out .= chr(substr($str, $ind, 3));
        $ind += 3;        
    }
}

echo $out;
```

Answer (score 2):

My fancy way with limitation that char could be from 32 to 128.

```
$value = '495051979899100';
preg_match_all('/3[2-9]|[4-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-8]/', $value, $matches);
var_dump(implode(array_map('chr',$matches[0])));
// string(7) "123abcd"
```

Comment: Finite state machine solves every task, right? I was opening a post just to type the same answer :)

Comment: @mudasobwa , it's short, but unreadable. It's hard to find out limitation in this code.

Comment: Do you really think this is _less_ readable, than the dances around `if`s and `chr`s? That’s the case of _very_ readable regexp, because it’s exactly reproduces the states in FSM.

Comment: i like the tapir photo way more than this regex.